# Can a meromorphic function have removable singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, meromorphic-functions

Authors usually give the following definition (or some variation) of meromorphic function:

> Let $G$ be a region (i.e. open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$). A
> function $f$ is said to be meromorphic in $G$ if it's holomorphic in
> $G$ except in a discrete set of poles.

However I think we should also consider removable singularities in the definition of meromorphic function. There is a theorem that says:

> If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in $G$ then $f/g$ is meromorphic in $G$.

This theorem is no longer true if we take the usual definition. Take for example $f,g:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}, f(z)=g(z)=z$ and define $h:\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}, h(z)=f(z)/g(z)$. Then $h=1$ in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, however $h$ is not meromorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ in the sense of the previous definition because $0$ is not a pole, is a removable singularity.

Most authors only mention poles in the definition of meromorphic functions, but I think that's not strictly correct. If I'm right, I would like to see an author considering removable singularities in the definition of meromorphic functions.

There is a similar question here [definition of meromorphic function : it may have removable singularities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540475/definition-of-meromorphic-function-it-may-have-removable-singularities) but I don't like the phrasing of the question and the answer.

I would like to have a reference text considering these details. For example Lang, Conway and Ahlfors all give the definition without removable singularities.

**Edit:** I wrote an answer in the other question that is correct but I don't think it addresses the most important points. Below I will write a proper answer

I think the book Lectures on Riemann surfaces by Otto Forster points to the right direction.
The most important thing is that for a (connected) Riemann Surface $X$, the set $\mathcal{M}(X)$ of meromorphic functions on $X$ should be a field and to do that, one sometimes has to extend the domain of definition of a given function. I'm just gonna copy the relevant part of the book here.

**1.12. Definition.** Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and $Y$ be an open subset of $X$.
By a *meromorphic function* on $Y$ we mean a holomorphic function $f: Y' \to \mathbb{C}$, where $Y' \subset Y$ is an open subset, such that the following hold:

1. $Y \setminus Y'$ contains only isolated points.
2. For every point $p \in Y \setminus Y'$, one has
   \begin{equation*}
     \lim_{x \to p}|f(x)| = \infty
   \end{equation*}
   The points of $Y \setminus Y'$ are called the *poles* of $f$.
   The set of all meromorphic functions on $Y$ is denoted by $\mathcal{M}(Y)$.

**1.13. Remarks**

1. Let $(U, z)$ be a coordinate neighborhood of a pole $p$ of $f$ with $z(p) = 0$.
   Then $f$ may be expanded in a Laurent series
   \begin{equation*}
     f = \sum_{v = -k}^\infty c_vz^v
   \end{equation*}
   in a neighborhood of $p$.
2. $\mathcal{M}(Y)$ has the natural structure of a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.
   First of all the sum and the product of two meromorphic functions $f, g \in \mathcal{M}(Y)$ are holomorphic functions at those points where both $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic.
   Then one holomorphically extends, using Riemann's Removable Singularities Theorem, $f + y$ (resp. $fg)$) across any singularities which are removable.

**1.16. Remark.** From (1.11) and (1.15) it follows that the Identity Theorem also holds for meromorphic functions on a Riemann surface.
Thus any function $f \in \mathcal{M}(X)$ which is not identically zero has only isolated zeroes.
This implies that $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is a field.

Comment: I would personally have phrased it as "except in a discrete set of singularities".

Comment: What are your definitions of *pole* and *removable singularity*?

Comment: "A discrete set of poles" can simply be empty.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That's not the problem here. What Zero is saying is that if $f(z) = z^2$ and $g(z) = z$, then $f/g$ isn't meromorphic in the complex plane, according to how he reads the definition, since $z = 0$ isn't a _pole_ of $\frac{z^2}z$.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, so I indicate another way to read it which is the one I use personally.

Comment: @lhf $a$ is a pole for $f$ if $\lim_{z\to a}|f(a)|=\infty$, $a$ is a removable singularity for $f$ if $f$ is not defined in $a$ but can be extended to a holomorphic function in $a$. That's not the point, though. The point is that the definition of meromorphic function should include removable singularities in the definition, as Arthur says.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Would you consider $\frac{z^2}{z}$ as a meromorphic function in the complex plane? Then you somehow need to deal with the singularity at $z = 0$. Depending on how you define "pole", it's not a pole, so the definition doesn't allow you to include it in your discrete set. And the function is certainly not holomorphic on all of $\Bbb C$, since it's not defined at the origin. This has nothing to do with the cardinality of the discrete set, but rather what you are allowed to put in there.

Comment: @Arthur What problems could arise from not making a distinction between $\frac{z^2}{z}$ and the entire function $z$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Domains of functions are pretty important in mathematics.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier They are two different functions, with different domains. Although the difference in domains is small, and their values agree everywhere their domains overlap. However, again, that is _not the issue_. The function $\frac1z$ is allowed to be meromorphic because it has a pole at $z = 0$, but $\frac{z^2}z$ apparently isn't because the singularity it has is not a pole. If you are so insistent that removable singlularities should always be removed, then what about $e^{1/z}$? Shouldn't we be allowed to call that meromorphic?

Comment: @Zero Yes, I know that domains are pretty important in maths, thank you, yet this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier The problem is that the usual definition of meromorphic function doesn't work perfectly well, It should require the inclusion of removable singularities, but for some reason most authors don't include that.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I don't know of a problem that could arise. That doesn't mean it's always correct. Or that it is always done.

Comment: @Arthur I know all that, this doesn't answer my question either. What problems can arise if you **define** the quotient $f/g$ to be the extension of the quotient to wherever it can be extended.

Comment: @Arthur regarding $e^{1/z}$, obviously it is not meromorphic, but I haven't said anything that would imply that - right?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier You hadn't, but those also aren't included by the mentioned definition. Turns out i was mistaken on that account, and essential singularities are actually disallowed for meromorphic functions. I did not know that. Now I wonder whether there is a reason for it.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I understand that this is a minor detail, but I like to get my definitions straight and "wherever it can be extended" is more or less what I'm saying when I propose to consider removable singularities in the defintion of meromorphic function.

Comment: @Arthur The reason for it is that the behaviour of a function near an essential singularity is so particular that it is natural to study them separately. Hence if it was allowed, you would constantly have to specify "let $f$ be meromorphic but without essential singularities" in your statements.

Comment: @Zero then I agree with you. It is also the sense of the answer given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540475/definition-of-meromorphic-function-it-may-have-removable-singularities

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That's not what is discussed here. Yes, I know that's a quite similar question (I wrote that in the question itself) but I prefer my phrasing of the question.

Comment: This question arose when I was trying to prove $f,g$ holomorphic implies $f/g$ meromorphic. There the precise definition matters a lot. I guess there is a point in math education where you have to fix small little things in proofs and definitions and learn lo live with it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, you need to allow for removable singularities in your definition of meromorphic for this case for this proposition to hold, the question is then is this a reasonable thing to do, and I think the answer to that is yes.